# MYSQL- Fetch one record per minute

Tags: mysql

I have records as per attached image. The last column has date and time of latitude and longitude recieved. Now i want to select one record per minute from the below data from date column. Is there any MySQL query to perform the operation?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMM8S.png

Comment: Table structure & what you have tried . pls..

Comment: where we can found table head??

Comment: this img link have the table with head

Comment: It's considered best at Stack Overflow to make your question standalone, including the text of sample data in the question itself. Could you edit your question to do that, so the next person looking for help can take advantage? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, colN, MAX(TimeAndDateColumn)
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE(TameAndDateColumn), HOUR(TimeAndDateColumn), Minute(TimeAndDateColumn)
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88a87/3) this is some other table but just to see how this work on example...

GL!

**EDIT** (query with your column name)

```
SELECT id, latitute, longitude, speed, MAX(`time`)
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY DATE(`time`), HOUR(`time`), Minute(`time`)
```

Comment: @SubaragaSundaram You're welcome. I'm glad that I could help :)

Comment: This above example return first record of the minute. How to fetch the last record of the minute

Answer (score 0):

You should have a column of time in to required precision. Then you can sort by time [last results to top] and use `limit 1` in the query.

Anyway you should have  a polling mechanism to trigger the query in each minute.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but I believe you're looking for a query that will filter the contents of your table to return at most one record for each "calendar minute." That is, if multiple records occur in the same calendar minute, you only get one of them.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') time_stamp,
       AVG(lat) lat, AVG(lon) lon
  FROM table
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
```

This will get you the average position computation in that minute. The trick is that `DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')` truncates `time_stamp` values to the immediately preceding calendar minute, and `GROUP BY` aggregates them.

You can get the first, or last, measurement in each minute, but it's harder. If your `id` values always go up as your `time_stamp` goes up, you can make this efficient. This query will fetch the first observation in each calendar minute.

```
 SELECT a.lat, a.lon, a.time_stamp
   FROM table a
   JOIN (
          SELECT MIN(id) id 
            FROM table
           GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
        ) b ON a.id = b.id
```

The inner query fetches the `id` of the earliest observation in each calendar minute, and the JOIN fetches the detail records associated with those id values. If you want the latest observation, use `MAX(id)` instead.

Note. I am a `GROUP BY` purist. I don't like the [nondeterministic behavior of the MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(long), AVG(lat), timestamp
FROM table
GROUP BY round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 60)
```